# Click on alert ok on modal in selenium

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I wish to click on ok button on alert  in modal, but unable to click on it.

```
// Capturing alert message.    
String alertMessage= driver.findElement(By.className("modal-header"))
                           .getText();

System.out.println(alertMessage);


String okButton= driver.findElement(By.xpath("//h4[contains(text(),'Woo Hoo! You have successfully registered! Look ou')]"))
                       .getText();
System.out.println(okButton);

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[contains(text(),'OK')]"))
      .click();
```

Tried this code but it's not working.This is what I am getting in console

> : unknown error: Element `<button type="button" class="close" ng-click="goTOLogin()">...</button>` is not clickable at point (897, 161). Other element would receive the click: `<div class="loader" style="display: block; opacity: 0.681626;"></div>`

This is the html code:

```html
<div id="registration" class="modal fade ng-scope in" role="dialog" style="display: block;">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-md add-brand">
    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content flat-modal">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" ng-click="goTOLogin()">X</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title common-title" style="" xpath="1">successfully registered</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body flat-body">
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
        <h4>Woo Hoo! You have successfully registered! Look out for the activation link in your email.</h4>
        <div class="modal-footer text-left">
          <button type="button" class="close" ng-click="goTOLogin()" style="">OK</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is your button disabled? Could you add html code?

Comment: I have posted,please check

Comment: String titleMessage= driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("//h4[@class='modal-title common-title']")).getText();
          
        System.out.println(titleMessage);
        
  
  String message= driver.findElement(By.xpath("//h4[contains(text(),'Woo Hoo! You have successfully registered! Look ou')]")).getText();
   System.out.println(message);
   
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[contains(text(),'OK')]")).click(); This what I tried.

Comment: Button is clickable.

Comment: Did you read the error message? It clearly states, `Other element would receive the click` followed by the HTML of the blocking element. From the HTML of that element, `class="loader"`, it looks like there is a loader/spinner something that pops up before you are attempting to click. You should add a wait for that element to appear and then another wait for that element to disappear. THEN try your click.

Comment: Thread.sleep(4000);
   driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(10,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10,TimeUnit.SECONDS);  I used this too,but didn't worked out,please help me

Comment: Now the error is coming like this: no such element:       Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//a[contains(text(),'Click Here')]"}

Answer (score 0):

You can press enter for accepting alerts.

```
Robot robot=new Robot();
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
```